# How to use PDE Source Lookup plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I installed PDE Source Lookup Plugin. However, I really have no idea how to use it? Supposedly, I think it should be similar to Java Source Attacher. But I did not find any button to trigger source code attaching.

Comment: If you mean [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pde-source-lookup) I don't think it has a separate UI you just use the normal 'Open Type' dialog.

Answer (score 0):

PDE Source lookup author here.

When you open a class from an Eclipse plugin, if the sources are not attached, the Class file editor is opened, where you can manually attach missing sources. The PDE Source lookup plugin automatically detects that no sources were found so will initiate a source lookup automatically, in all available software sites (aka p2 repositories). If sources are found, they're downloaded and attached automatically, the Class file editor is then replaced by the proper source file. So this is on-demand, lazy source download.

Now, you can also fetch all sources at once from the "Plug-in Dependencies" classpath container, in the Explorer view, with a right-click and select `Download Bundle Sources`.